# How to compress the recored video in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, video, compression

I have an iPhone app in which i am recording video and playing that video it works fine.But the file size which comes is huge 3MB for 30 seconds any idea or way to compress to the file here i want when compress button is clicked on Screen it should compress the recorded video.

```
  Saved Video 



    NSURL*videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    NSLog(@"found a video");

    videoData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL] retain];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:SS"];
    NSDate *now = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDate* theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];


NSString*myDate=[dateFormat stringFromDate:theDate];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default Album"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];



NSString*test=@"test";


NSString*testUser=[test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];



videopath= [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp4",documentsDirectory,testUser]] autorelease];
    BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:videopath atomically:NO];

    NSLog(@"Successs:::: %@", success ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    NSLog(@"video path --> %@",videopath);

NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videopath];
AVURLAsset *avUrl = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:movieURL];
CMTime time1 = [avUrl duration];  
int seconds = ceil(time1.value/time1.timescale);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
+ (void)convertVideoToLowQualityWithInputURL:(NSURL*)inputURL outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL successHandler:(void (^)())successHandler failureHandler:(void (^)(NSError *))failureHandler {
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtURL:outputURL]) [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) {
        if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
            successHandler();
        } else {
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:domain code:code userInfo:userInfo]; 
            failureHandler(error); 
        }
     }];
}
```